# Displaying placeholder for an image in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display a RecyclerView which initially loads a skeleton view before getting the data from API. In the below example, a simple imageview and a text is being displayed.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_store_offer_display"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Foo FOO"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I would like to know how to make my Recyclerview show the view even before the image/text is loaded. I am using Picasso to load image. mikepenz FastAdapter for displaying RecyclerView content.

I also tried to use a progressbar as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12342168/371557. But progressbar was never shown even if the visibility is set to VISIBLE.

Comment: Could you not just specify the image in your xml? `android:src="@drawable/placeholder"`

Comment: can you show your code where to set image in Picasso..

Comment: setting ```android:src="@drawable/placeholder"``` makes it look static.. Hence I wanted to display a progressbar :) any other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

you can use something like

```
picasso.load(url)
    .placeholder( R.drawable.place_holder )
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer John. Is it possible to set a animating object as a place holder?

Comment: yes, your drawable can be something like  `<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_image"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>`

Comment: For some strange reason, my recyclerview is acting weird. It actually never loads the placeholder image. it switches between placeholder and the image from URL just in split second difference. until then the UI shows no sign of RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

```
            <!--You Would Apply Like this-->
              Picasso.load(url)
                                .placeholder( R.drawable.img_place_holder)
                                .into(imageView);

        <!--Use ProgressBar-->
                   <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/sliding_popup_window"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bank_info_toolbar"
                >

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>

//Your ProgressBar code
class Synch extends AsynchTask<void, void, void> {
    public void onPreExecute() {
      //your code
      progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }

  public void doinBackground() {
    //Your Code
  }

  public void onPostExecute() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
```